# Customizing a AlertDailog.Builder Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to customize my AlertDailog. I am OK with the default layout of the AlertDailog, so i  don't want to set any particular view to my dailog, I just want to change small things like text color, background color etc.

I have tried two approaches, which seems to be correct but surprisingly both of them does not work.

First, I have tried to create the AlertDailog with a custom style like :

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,R.style.cust_dialog);
```

which gives me output like

[image]

I did not understand why there it is a dailog within a box and even the text color did not change, so i have tried another way.

I created a ContextThemeWrapper and passed it to AlertDailog.Builder

```
    ContextThemeWrapper ctw = new ContextThemeWrapper(this,R.style.cust_dialog);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctw);
```

The output was

[image]

still the text color or background was not changed.

my cust_dialog.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="cust_dialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/brown</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Can somebody tell me what am i doing wrong or what is the correct way to do this?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok it's juts a bit more complicated than the solution you tried, but why did you not build a complete custom dialog ?

I have already done this and it works like a charm.
You just need to :

1. create a layout xml for you dialog view like a classic view
2. create a class with extends Dialog
3. finally use your custom dialog like other

If you want example code let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, theming a dialog is slightly more complex than just changing the attributes `windowBackground` and `textColor`. You should define your theme like this:

```
<style name="YourAlertDialogTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_major</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_minor</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">...</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceMedium">...</item>
    <item name="android:borderlessButtonStyle">...</item>
    <item name="android:buttonBarStyle">...</item>
</style>
```

I wrote a complete blog post detailing how to define and link each element's style, [here](http://blog.supenta.com/2014/07/02/how-to-style-alertdialogs-like-a-pro/). You'll be able to do stuff like:

[image: Please have better taste than that]

(Please have better taste than that)